# the use of the word with the meaning

Tags: noun-phrases

> In particular, from the fourth century onwards, the word is employed in the papyri as a monastic title, in both the masculine and feminine genders,[19] and by the late sixth century the use of **the word with the meaning "monk" or "nun"** is well established.[20] It is likely, then, that the word here, found always in conjunction with the name, is being used to indicate that Tsone was a nun.

[Source](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/i/icp/7523866.0025.110/--nun-s-dispute-with-her-mother-in-plond-v-1731?rgn=main;view=fulltext)

Is the bold part a noun phrase and the object of "of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that "with the meaning of 'monk' or 'nun'" is a separate prepositional phrase attached to "the use".

What did they use? The word.

How did they use it? With this particular meaning.

We can't analyze "with the meaning of..." as a modifier of "the word" specifying which word we're using, because the meaning here is that this word is or was used with several different meanings, and one of these meanings became common by the late sixth century.